# How to execute multiple k-means's with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm quite new to spark and not very familiar with python. I'm using spark 2.2.

I have a hive table like below:

```
+----------+-------+
| category | point |
+----------+-------+
```

I need to cluster the points of each category, using k-means algorithm, with pyspark.

I write code something like:

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

def run():
  rawData = sparkSession.sql('select category, point from my_table')
  groupedData = rawData.groupBy("category").agg(collect_list("point").alias("point_list"))
  groupedData.rdd.map(lambda row: kmeans(row.point_list, row.category))

def kmeans(points, category):
  kmeans = KMeans(k=10, initMode='k-means||')
  df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense(x),) for x in points], ["features"])
  model = kmeans.fit(df)
  predictions = model.transform(df)
  return (['kmeans: ' + str(row.prediction) for row in predictions.collect()], category)
```

And it gives me some error like:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o133.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

I guess it may because worker executors, who is running my `kmeans` method, don't have the `sparkSession` which created by driver. But how to solve this?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You get that error because createdataframe cannot be called in methods that run in executors. For spark 2.2 you can use ml or mllib library to use kmeans. You should use vector.dense for your feature set. Here are the code samples of using kmeans for both libraries:

[Spark mllib clustering](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html#k-means)

[Spark ml clustering](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-clustering.html)

Comment: I know that. My code follows the samples you give. But my point is, how to use kmeans for *multiple* point sets?

Comment: You want to use kmeans for each category seperately ? Can you share  sample data?

Comment: Yes, for each category seperately. Sorry raw data is private and also too large to show. Mock data like k=2, (category=1, (0,0), (1,1), (8,8), (9,9), ), (category=2, (0,1), (1,0), (8,9), (9,8), ). I don't wanna gather (0,0) from category 1 and (0,1) from category 2 together.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade spark version? Using pandas_udf could be a solution but it can be used with  spark 2.3 or higher.

Comment: Nah the image is in other team and is complex to modify or install/upgrade dependencies. Eventually I re-implemented the k-means for re-partition :-) Thank you for help!